# jquery - problem with synchronize ajax and dialogbox in function

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have problem with synchronizing results of function I get with AJAX with that function.
The idea is that I send AJAX request, then after reciving answer I open dialogbox, and after user confirmation function returns proper value. Problem is that my function (even if I set ajax request not to be async) doesn't wait for response and returns value before catching user action.
Here is a code:

```
checkColisions = function(event) {
        var parsedStart = Date.parse(event.start);
        var parsedEnd = Date.parse(event.end);
        var returnValue = true;

        returnValue = $.ajax({
          async: false,
          url: '<?php echo url_for('lecture/ajaxCheckColisions')?>',
          data: ({id: event.eid, name:event.title, start: parsedStart, end: parsedEnd}),
          success: function(data) {
              if(data == 'no-colisions')
              {
                  returnValue = false; //do nothing
              }
              else
              {
                  $("#dialog-colisions").dialog({
                        resizable: false,
                        open: function() {
                            $('#dialog-colisions').text()
                            $('#dialog-colisions').append('<p>Found colisions:</p>');
                            $('#dialog-colisions').append(data);
                        },
                        height:300,
                        modal: true,
                        buttons: {
                            'Continue': function(){                                    
                                $(this).dialog('close');
                                returnValue = false;
                            },
                            'Cancel': function() {
                                $(this).dialog('close');
                                returnValue = true;
                            }
                        }

                  });
              }
          },
          error: function(data) {
          alert('error' +data);
          }
        });
        return returnValue;
    };

enter code here
```

returnValue should be set by dialogbox, but it's not.
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't try to "block" a thread within your browser. A better solution is to open the dialog and trigger the adequate action from the callbacks that jquery is providing to you.

You are now having something like

```
var returnValue= checkColisions(e);//go to server and open a popup
if(returnValue==true){
 doCollistionStuff(); 
}else{
 noCollitionDetected();
}
```

My suggestion is to change the dialog to something like:

```
$("#dialog-colisions").dialog({
                        resizable: false,
                        open: function() {
                            $('#dialog-colisions').text()
                            $('#dialog-colisions').append('<p>Found colisions:</p>');
                            $('#dialog-colisions').append(data);
                        },
                        height:300,
                        modal: true,
                        buttons: {
                            'Continue': function(){                                    
                               doCollistionStuff();
                            },
                            'Cancel': function() {
                               noCollitionDetected();
                            }
                        }

                  });
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but in my case it seems that I have to use it just in way like in your first code, because this main function (checkColisions) is called by few different functions of FullCalendar (like drop, eventDrop and eventClick) and every of them makes other collisionStuff.

Comment: I mean that function checkColisions is used in few different parts of code, and every of that part do something different after getting the result. So according to that, it's not possible to take action in for example Continue-button function, because that's body depends of that part of code witch called checkCollisions function. Just seems to be good to return value - like now, and allow that part of code to decide what to do with result, like in yours:
var returnValue= checkColisions(e);
if(returnValue==true){
 doCollistionStuff(); 
}else{
 noCollitionDetected();
}